# setTimeout/Loop... still confused

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

So I've been all over this since yesterday afternoon. I have done various iterations of the basic code I have trying to get the result I want (I want dropping markers in order every xx ms), but nothing works. The result I get is either they go all at once or not at all. I'm fairly certain the "not at all" problems are due to syntax errors I correct and get the "all at once".

So here's the function...

```
    function marker(location) 
    {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.5, -98.35);
        var mapOptions = 
        {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < location.length; i++) 

        {


            marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[i][1], location[i][2]),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map
            }
            );


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) 
            {

                return function () 
                {
                    infowindow.setContent(location[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }

            }
            )(marker, i));


        }

    }
```

I think what I should be doing is within the for, like this...

```
        for (i = 0; i < location.length; i++) 

        {
           setTimeout(function() { 

            marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[i][1], location[i][2]),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map
            }
            );


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) 
            {

                return function () 
                {
                    infowindow.setContent(location[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }

            }
            )(marker, i));
            }, 1000)
        }
```

But this doesn't work, and neither do the other things I've tried. I have looked at a lot of explanations, most of which seem to make sense, but I can'e figure this out and I think it's more about the for loop than anything else.

As an example, I've also tried encapsulating the addlistener within the setTimeout as well, thinking if I run the addlistener code and wait it will work. I guess where I am is that I need to come up with a way to break out of the loop and wait for the called function to return something, but I m not sure how to do this.

If someone can just tell me I am on the right track or not I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you should add `var` to `marker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want all your results at once, you need to give different times, because the loop is executed instantly and all the timeout are computed from the time of this execution :

```
setTimeout(function() { 

}, 1000*i);
```

And to avoid the problem of all iterations using the same value of `i`, protect it in a closure using

```
for (i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
   (function(i){
       setTimeout(function() { 

       }, 1000*i);
   })(i);
}
```

Comment: OK. That did it, thanks! I just need to understand it now, which I really still don't get. I will come back and look at your answer after a while so I can understand this. Making it work is of course important, but understanding is more important to me. Thanks again

Comment: @jsteffler [This might be a useful read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).